# How to set the copy window to be expanded always in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

When copying files in Windows 7 there is an option to view more details where you can see the transfer rate and how much data is left for copying.

How can I set Windows to always show these details without needing to press the more details button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been looking around and you're not the only one requesting this feature. But I fear this isn't possible unless you resort to third party software.

In which case [I can recommend TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php)

> TeraCopy is a compact program designed
>   to copy and move files at the maximum
>   possible speed, providing the user a
>   lot of features:
>
> - Copy files faster. TeraCopy uses dynamically adjusted buffers to reduce
>     seek times.  - Asynchronous copy
>     speeds up file transfer between two
>     physical hard drives.
> - Pause and resume file transfers. Pause copy process at any time to free
>     up system resources and continue with
>     a single click.
> - Error recovery. In case of copy error, TeraCopy will try several times
>     and in the worse case just skips the
>     file, not terminating the entire
>     transfer.
> - Interactive file list. TeraCopy shows failed file transfers and lets
>     you fix the problem and recopy only
>     problem files.
> - Shell integration. TeraCopy can completely replace Explorer copy and
>     move functions, allowing you work with
>     files as usual.
> - Full Unicode support.
> - Windows 7 x64 support.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I hope you are wrong :) I will wait acouple more days to see if someone has a solution without a 3rd party software.

Comment: For your sake I hope I'm wrong too ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, no new answers... I guess this must be it!